# AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto3, dask

I hoped to retrieve the csv file stored in S3 using Dask. Due to its extremely large size, it is impossible to use pandas dataframe as an alternative.
However, I encountered the error as the title and the following is my code snippet:

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region_name='us-east-1'
)
ratingObject = client.get_object(
    Bucket=clientResponse['Buckets'][0]['Name'],
    Key='data lake/rating.csv'
)
rating = dd.read_csv(ratingObject['Body'])
```

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: where do you use `startswith'`? Also can you show full error message?

Comment: I didn't use `startswith`, the problem occurred in the final line.

Comment: You can try: `rating = dd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(ratingObject['Body']))` after `import io`.

Comment: How did it go? Did you try?